# pyplot: Don't plot 0 on the x-axis

Tags: matplotlib

I have a code that counts the primes from 1 to n.
Now I want to plot the result, but I don't want the axis to start at 0, but by 1.
This is my code:

```
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import gmpy2

def pi_count(n):
    result = []
    count = 0
    for h in range(1, n+1):
        if gmpy2.is_prime(h):
            count += 1
        result.append(count)
    return result

lim = 10**3
liste = pi_count(lim)

plt.plot(list(range(1, lim+1)), liste)
plt.show()
```

and it results in this plot.
How can I change the x-Axis to start at 1?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Axes.set_xticks' of matplotlib to manually change the labels of the xticks (see documentation [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticks.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticks)).

Here is an example (though not very elegant) that produces the desired output

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
ax.plot(list(range(1, lim+1)), liste)
curr_labels = ax.get_xticklabels()
curr_labels[1] = '1'
ax.set_xticks(ticks=ax.get_xticks()[1:], labels=curr_labels[1:])
plt.show()
```